# I want to get rid of this block in jupyter notebook's RISE

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, reveal.js, rise

I am trying to load a [widget](https://github.com/datacamp/datacamp-light) (through HTML code) into my Jupyter Notebook's cell. I am trying out ways to get rid of the block shown on left side which shows "click to scroll output;double click to hide" in the below picture:
[image]

It's obtrusive. And also is there a way i can make the frame of the slide (highlighted in blue) larger (for only the current cell) so that it's clearer for view ?

I tried changing the "height" and "width" of RISE extension from "Nbextensions" tab but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound ridiculous but, have you tried to remove this block using your browser's element inspector?

## Example (remove code input)

### Slide before deleting code input

[image: Slide before deleting code input]

### Selecting correct div

[image: Selecting correct div]

### Deleting input div

[image: Deleting input div]

### Slide after deleting code input

[image: Slide after deleting code input]

*Of course it's just a temporarily solution and as soon as you refresh/reload your notebook it will be back as before.*